# Is a person using the pronoun "I" uncapitalized considered rude or uneducated?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, politeness

Like what i am demonstrating here. To be honest i didn't even know about it until much later when i discovered the Grammarly app and i was like "it even exists?". Now it has quite become my bad habit especially in real-time messaging. I am aware that it is incorrect but when the conversation is going fast i just kind of forget to give it one more keypress and bam there goes my grammar.

Again forgive me if the passage above sounds rude or something. I just want to clarify it once and for all.

Comment: Yes, I may consider it uneducated.  But no worse than *u* for *you* or *b4* for *before*.

Comment: It's considered "careless" at best.  Maybe OK for emails, but should not be used in, eg, EL&U posts.

Comment: of course, if you are e. e. cummings you can get away with it.

Comment: It is hard to tell whether a person is using a capital _I_ or not, if they're speaking English. So it isn't really important for most politeness.

Comment: Good that you are aware of the difference and welcome to the site. No one cares a whit [at all] what you use for texting or how but writing [not txting] is where the real world begins. In professional communications or letters 'i' comes across as being painfully, ridiculously modest. As such it might be considered overtly immodest. You are free to use as you wish but managing expectations is important to those we write to. I must capitalize nouns in German which is odd to me [could not spell unmoglich]. Follow along or strike out on a new path.